# How to use the pigpen font with XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am trying to use the pigpen font https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/pigpen by Oliver Corff.

The pigpen.tex file is *really* small and seems equivalent to the following:

```
\font\pp=pigpen
```

but the following won't produce a valid PDF using xetex

```
\font\pp=pigpen

{\pp HELLO WORLD}

\bye
```

> `Sorry, pfa format not supported`

What am I missing?

Comment: Your approach works for me when processed by PdfTeX but not XeTeX. I'm not familiar with XeTeX.

Comment: When I compile with XeTex to DVI and then to PDF, I can get PDF output. If I try to compile XeTex to PDF, I can't get output.

Comment: Does ``\usepackage{pigpen.sty}`` in XeLaTeX work for you?

Comment: @Davislor texlive xdvpdfmx can not include the supplied font, I just posted an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

If I run your example in texlive 2022  get

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Sorry, pfa format not supported; please convert the font to pfb, e.g., with t1binary.
```

and indeed texlive does only have a `pfa` version rather than the compressed `pfb` form.

So...

```
t1binary /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/pigpen/pigpen.pfa  pigpen.pfb
```

Makes a `pigpen.pfb` in the current directory

```
cp  /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/pigpen/pigpen.map .
```

makes a `pigpen.map` which looks like

```
pigpen <<pigpen.pfa
```

edit that so it says

```
pigpen <<pigpen.pfb
```

Then

```
xetex --no-pdf yourfile
```

will make `yourfile.xdv` and `xdvipdfmx` will make the pdf if you supply the modified map

```
xdvipdfmx -f pigpen.map yourfile.xdv
```

produces a PDF with the output above.

Answer (score 6):

I made an experiment. I copied the `pigpen.pfa` file from

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/pigpen/pigpen.pfa
```

to a working directory with the name `originalpigpen.pfa` and ran

```
t1binary originalpigpen.pfa -o pigpen.pfa
```

(yes, the produced PFB file with extension `.pfa`). Running your example file is now successful.

Now you can use the personal tree

```
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME)/fonts/type1/public/pigpen
mv pigpen.pfa $(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME)/fonts/type1/public/pigpen
```

and the PFB file masqueraded as PFA will be found with precedence over the distributed one.

[image]

I made a [query on the TeX Live list](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2022-November/048671.html), let's see what happens. The hack suggested above should be innocuous when the file format is changed at the distribution level.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me in plain (Xe)TeX:

```
\input pigpen
\mypigpenfont
HELLO WORLD
\bye
```

[image: Pigpen sample]

It embeds a type 3 (bitmap) font, rather than a vector font.

Comment: That's really strange, do you know why?

Comment: Can you say what version of xetex and (especially) xdvipdfmx  you have, I get `xdvipdfmx:fatal: Sorry, pfa format not supported; please convert the font to pfb, e.g., with t1binary.`  and there is only  pigpen.pfa but (weirdly) I get the same error if I use `t1binary` to make a pfb file in same directory

Comment: Personally, `XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/MacPorts 2022.62882_0)` and `This is xdvipdfmx Version 20211117 by the DVIPDFMx project team, modified for TeX Live,`

Comment: it works on windows by converting the font with mktexpk to a bitmap font (zoom in and look at the corners), to get a vector font one has to use one of the other answers.